# aireplay - reading but not sending

Tags: aircrack-ng, packet-injection

I'm trying aircrack injection, everything is working I authenticated, but aireplay is not working

```
aireplay-ng -3 -b 00:12:2A:01:74:05 -h 78:e4:00:87:71:8b mon0
18:53:03  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 00:12:2A:01:74:05) on channel 7
Saving ARP requests in replay_arp-0817-185303.cap
You should also start airodump-ng to capture replies.
Read 4988 packets (0 ARPs, 4 ACKs), sent 0 packets...(0 pps)
```

Why isn't it  working? Why isn't it sending packets?

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

I tested injection on injection test in aircrack tutorial, despite driver wasn't patched.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, some WiFi cards don't allow injection – running Linux in a virtual machine, the adapter will have to be breached first. So make sure that is covered.